# Using the android scale type

Tags: android, android-layout

```
 <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/read_news_only"
  android:scaleType="centerInside"
  android:alpha="0.7"
  android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:src="@drawable/read_news_only" />
```

I have this ImageView on my welcome screen among with my logo, sign-up and sign-in images. So I went ahead to try it on my HTC One device, and it turned out to be very small (this is for all), so I tried using the scaling, which didn't work. I also tried fitXY, which didn't make it pretty.

Is there any way to resize images to the device's dimensions without making it look bad?

Edit:

It needs to look like this:

[image]

But it look like this:

[image]

Comment: are you talking about the button on the bottom? Why do you fill width and height if it doesnt fill the whole screen?

Comment: Yes I am talking about the button on the bottom. I was experimenting if that changed anything. Edit: the others are relatively small as well on my HTC One.

Comment: It would work better if the text is not in the image. If images with text get scaled, it often get's unreadable

Comment: `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` may work if you can fix one dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Check below a representation for all android scale types[image: Android scale type]